# Turning 'tvservice' on and off leaves screen blank

Tags: power, hdmi, qt

I'm running the Qt5 application on my raspberry pi and I would like to introduce some kind of a power-saving feature.

I don't use x11 or wayland, because I don't need it, but I use gles2 (OpenGL for Embedded Systems).

I want to use `tvservice --off` and `tvservice --preferred` to toggle between turned off / turned on screen.

My problem is that when I call `tvservice --preferred` the display turns on but the screen is black (no application output is shown).

**Question:**
How can I turn it on and see the application that was running previously?

**Tested:**
When I restart the Qt5 application - it's being displayed correctly.

Changing foreground virtual terminal with `chvt` (as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/simlun/1b27b14d707abbba8fc1)) does not help.

Changing framebuffer depth to different and back again with `fbset -depth 16 ; fbset -depth 32` (I've seen it on some forum, cannot find which) also does not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`tvservice` is not the best to turn off and on the screen.

Much better way to do this (found after a day of searching) is using `vcgencmd` command (more on this [here](http://www.elinux.org/RPI_vcgencmd_usage)).

`vcgencmd display_power 0` turns off the screen

`vcgencmd display_power 1` turns on the screen

This allows the Qt application to be visible on the screen after turning it off and back on.

Comment: This is perfect! I was looking for something like this for a Pi3..

Comment: Thanks, @lewiatan - I had been using tvservice with Raspian Stretch but it had the problems described in the original question when I switched to Buster. `vcgencmd` works as hoped.

Comment: I searched for ages with this problem, thanks for posting this. Like @EricSmith, I'm also using Raspian Buster and found that `tvservice` just wouldn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: On my model 1 type B vcgencmd does nothing but tvservice works with buster. Pls. refer to https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=257631

Comment: Works on Raspian Buster 32 bit on a Pi4 with a single monitor.